# ArcGis json transform to geojson

Tags: json, geojson, arcgis, topojson, ogr2ogr

I am currently working with geospatial data and I have encountered a situation where I need to convert data from an ArcGIS JSON format into a GeoJSON format. I understand that GDAL, specifically its ogr2ogr tool, is a powerful library that can be used for this kind of data transformation. How to use GDAL's ogr2ogr utility to effectively transform an ArcGIS JSON file into a GeoJSON file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you're getting the data from, but if the data is hosted on an arcgis server, you can ask for it in GeoJSON directly instead of having it returned in a different JSON format that you then have to convert.

For example:

- https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Earthquakes_Since1970/FeatureServer/0/query?where=magnitude%3E8.3&f=json
- https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Earthquakes_Since1970/FeatureServer/0/query?where=magnitude%3E8.3&f=geojson

Ref: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-feature-service-layer-.htm

Answer (score 1):

I came across this convertor online: https://ogre.adc4gis.com/